# How to add an activity with tabs to my project

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to add an activity to my project with navigation tabs using the wizard provided by eclipse. I got an error while trying to open the generated activity-template from my code.

File -> New -> Android Activity -> Blank Activity -> Navigation Type =

Activity Name: TabsActivity
Navigation Type: Fixed Tabs + Swipe: Finish

A template is created but when I'm trying to open the new activity with an intent I got a NullPointerException as a runtime error.

```
Intent tabs = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TabsActivity.class);
startActivity(tabs);
```

Should the generated activity template work immediately, or is the additional steps installing/integrating the new activity with the rest of the project.

Comment: Well the information is not enough. The templates also change according to the ADB version. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to provide context for the intent constructor, like this:

```
Intent tabs = new Intent(this, TabsActivity.class);
startActivity(tabs);
```

Comment: Also, double check that your new activity is registered in your AndroidMAnifest.xml file, just in case.